# How to partition a set of positive integers as evenly as possible?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

I want to partition a set of positive integers into $n$ subsets as evenly as possible. Summation of these subsets should be close to each other as much as possible.

I have read something about NP-completeness but I got confused. Can someone suggest a method in *-for-dummies* fashion?

Comment: This is the optimization version of the $k$-[partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), a classical problem. If the number of partitions were a power of $2$, it would be easier.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Would you refer me to document which discusses the case where number of partitions are power of 2 and the numbers in the set are not consecutive (not 10, 9, 8, ... but 10, 7, 2, ...).

Comment: If the number of partitions is a power of $2$, then you can break the original problem into several instances of the $2$-partition problem, each of which can be solved using dynamic programming.

Comment: Take a look at [THE EASIEST HARD PROBLEM](http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/bph-publications/AmSci-2002-03-Hayes-NPP.pdf) (2002).

Comment: [This paper](http://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/096.pdf) linked from the Wikipedia partition problem page looks like a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy method: Sort the numbers and start with the biggest and the go to the smallest. Always put the next number in the subset with the smallest sum.

Comment: This gives (9+1=10), (7+2=9), (5) but there is a better way such as (7+1=8), (5+2=7), (9).

Comment: 9 -> G1 , 7-> G2, 5->G3, 2->G3 (because G3 has the smallest sum) and then the last one into G2. 1->G2. Which is optimal for this example. But the algorithm will not find the optimal in general.